# How to Design SharePoint 2013 website in Visual Studio 2013 locally

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Whats the Solution to design a sharepoint website by using Visual Studio 2013 on local machine
I am beginner with SharePoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, decide whether to develop on a local computer where SharePoint 2013 is installed or to use an Office 365 Developer Site. If you want to distribute apps for SharePoint through an app catalog, such as apps for SharePoint that have full control permissions (which you cannot deploy to an Office 365 site), you’ll want to work with a full installation of SharePoint 2013 on a local computer. We provide the steps to set up a local installation of SharePoint 2013 and begin developing apps for SharePoint in this article.

Now follow the steps in this Techent to configure your envinroment.

[How to: Set up an on-premises development environment for apps for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923.aspx)